# Migrating cruisecontrol to jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol, auto-build

I want to migrate My jobs from cruisecontrol to Jenkins.

What are the steps that I need to do to achieve this ?

Comment: Mention here what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install Jenkins

2) Use the Jenkins docs to create some simple jobs (in other words, learn how Jenkins works but using it for some simple demo projects)

3) Examine your existing cruise control jobs and break them up into groups whose builds are similar.

4) Migrate one group at a time by first creating a Jenkins job form one of the Cruise Control projects, then create the other jobs based on the first (Jenkins lets you create new jobs based on an existing job).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have specific needs, the migration is easy as CruiseControl.NET **simply execute task and build reports**, as all other continuous integration tools.

- Simply create new tasks in Jenkins
- Fill it with the executable tasks you had in CC.NET
- (eventually) need to improve the dashboard if you
  want specific information

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify your Build/Test/Deploy Steps or of any special needs , 
But as a Vanilla CI would be 
1) Build using MSBuild 
2) Test Using MSTest 
3) Deploy using MSBuild/NANt/ANT/Powershell or even Batch scripts .

All Those steps can be easily replicated to Jenkins Because there are dedicated plugins for all of them .

I would suggest for you to select a simple Build>Test>Deploy Flow from CC.NET and recreate it in Jenkins, after that copying it for other projects,